# Highcharts - how do I position categories aligned with tick marks as separations between columns?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an histogram dislpayed with a column chart: [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_deschamps/6v8awuwh/1/).

The bars contain data between intervals (from 0% to 10%, 10% to 20%, etc...).

Therefore I would like to represent the different interval values [0%, ..., 100%] as numbers aligned with the tick marks that are currently separating columns.

If I use

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ["0%", "10%", "20%", "30%", "40%", "50%", "60%", "70%", "80%", "90%", "100%"],
},
```

the categories end up aligned below each bar.
And if I add

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {           
       pointPlacement: 0.5
   }
},
```

that will move the columns to the right. But as a result, my last category is off-chart.

There's got to be a better way to do this.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I actually think your issue is that you have 11 categories and only 10 values.  THere isn't a value for 100% so nothing renders by default.  If you remove 0% or add another value to your series it renders fine.

Comment: Yes, it's because these labels represent the frontier between the different categories, therefore if there is n categories, there is n+1 label if you want to enclose all of them between two limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is fine and I couldn't find a better way. As `Rooster` said in the comments your `data` don't match the `categories`.

You can't remove the `0%` category because your first data is between 0% and 10% not 10% to 20%. Therefore you need to add a `null` at the end of your data, which will be like this:

```
data: [20, 24, 30, 40, 60, 80, 90, 96, 100, 102, null]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6v8awuwh/3/

Hope this is what you want.